# laravel check if update have some changes using query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-query-builder

How can i know about the updated changes using query builder in my laravel application code is given below
 public function update(Request $request, Announcement $announcement)
    {

```
     $announcement_update = DB::table('announcement')
        ->where('id', $request->announcement_id)
        ->update($announcement_data);

    if($announcement_update){
        return redirect('announcement')->with('success','Announcement updated               successfully');
    }
    elseif(need conditionfor this){
        return redirect('editAnnouncement/'.encrypt($request->announcement_id))
        ->with('error','NO changes have been made in the form fields');
    }
    else{
        return redirect('editAnnouncement/'.encrypt($request->announcement_id))
        ->with('error','There seems some error in updating announcement. Please try again');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, reformat you code.

Comment: Explain what's your issue! Look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez when updating data to the table it returns 0 for failed and 1 for success. I just to find if there is any change in the post/form fileds because in this case it only return 0 and show error that data not updated.

Answer (score 0):

An **Update** query will return the number of rows that where affected. you can catch an exception or query error using the `\Illuminate\Database\QueryException` exception.

```
try {
    $announcement_update = DB::table('announcement')
        ->where('id', $request->announcement_id)
        ->update($announcement_data);

    if($announcement_update > 0){
        return redirect('announcement')->with('success','Announcement updated               successfully');
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect('editAnnouncement/'.encrypt($request->announcement_id))
        ->with('error','NO changes have been made in the form fields');
    }

} catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
    return redirect('editAnnouncement/'.encrypt($request->announcement_id))
    ->with('error','There seems some error in updating announcement. Please try again');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could write an event and fire it on update, and store changes